# pulseaudio setup, to listen my left HDMI display as left speaker and my right as right speaker

Tags: pulseaudio, hdmi, displayport

I have two displays in front of me and both are connected with DP/HDMI.

Now I try to setup Pulseaudio to have a sink which is mapped as:

Both speakers (R/L) from my left displays should go to the left channel
and
Both speakers (R/L) from my right display should go to the right channel

I currently have set them as a combined-sink.

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0 sink_properties="device.description='NVIDIA DP #1'"
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1 sink_properties="device.description='NVIDIA DP #2'"
load-module module-combine-sink sink_name="DP1+2" sink_properties=device.description=Combined-DP slaves=alsa_output.hdmi_CARD_NVidia_DEV_0,alsa_output.hdmi_CARD_NVidia_DEV_1 channels=2
```

But then left and right is totally mixed up :)

Comment: You will need channel mapping and `module-remap-sink`, as you want to separate the left and right channel.

Comment: the question is how?

Comment: First thing I'd try is one remap-sink in front of each hdmi sink, mapping left to left&right and right to left&right, and then a combine sink with those remap-sinks.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?